# How do I properly highlight type hints for python in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm using visual studio Code w/ Python 3.6 and was wondering how to properly highlight type hints.

For example built in types (such as str or bool) get highlighted correctly. But my custom classes or imports such as datetime remain white. (Both for variable declarations and function returns).

How do I get them also to highlight a different color?

[image: Sample python code]

Answer (score -1):

1. Put your cursor over the text whose come you want to change.
2. In the command palette, type `inspect`and choose 'inspect tokens'.
3. In the pop up that appears, note the technical name of the time you're on.  (Often the topmost scope)
4. In settings.json, set the color and font of the associated text mate rule.  See more in that in the official docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide